# Mathematica function equivalent to MATLAB's residue function (partial fraction expansion)

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I am looking for a Mathematica function equivalent to MATLAB's [`residue`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/residue.html) function.

If there is no Mathematica equivalent, I would like to write a function that given the coefficients of two polynomials $a$ and $b$, outputs the residues $r$, the poles $p$ and the term $k$ of the partial fraction expansion of $\frac{b}{a}$:

$\frac{b(x)}{a(x)} = \frac{b_m x^m + b_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \dots + b_1 x + b_0}{a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1 x + a_0} = \frac{r_n}{x-p_n} + \dots + \frac{r_2}{x-p_2} + \frac{r_1}{x-p_1} + k(x) \tag{1}$

Two lists as inputs:

> coefficients of the polynomial $a = \{a_n, \dots, a_2, a_1\}$
> coefficients of the polynomial $b = \{b_m, \dots, b_2, b_1\}$

Three lists as outputs:

> residues $r = \{r_n, \dots, r_2, r_1\}$
> poles    $p = \{p_n, \dots, p_2, p_1\}$
> polynomial $k = \{\dots\}$

I know how to create the polynomials $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ from the input lists $a$ and $b$ and how to do a partial fraction expansion. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to compute $r$, $p$ and $k$:

```
Residues[a_,b_] :=
Module[{apoly, bpoly,f,x},
(* build polynomials *)
bpoly = FromDigits[b, x];
apoly = FromDigits[a, x];
(* partial fraction expansion *)
f = Apart[Expand[bpoly]/Expand[apoly]];

r = ???;
p = ???;
k = ???;

{r,p,k}
]
```

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I do not want to simply do a partial fraction expansion (which can be done using Apart) but rather extract the residues, poles and constant term from this expansion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get the poles with

```
p = x /. Solve[apoly == 0, x]
```

and the residues with

```
r = RootReduce[Residue[f, {x, #}]] & /@ p
```

I don't know how to get `k` directly though, except to do a difference (very inefficient):

```
k = f - Total[r/(x - p)] // Together // FullSimplify
```

All together in one function:

```
residue[num_, denom_] := Module[{apoly, bpoly, f, p, r, k},
  bpoly = FromDigits[num, x];
  apoly = FromDigits[denom, x];
  f = bpoly/apoly;
  p = x /. Solve[apoly == 0, x];
  r = RootReduce[Residue[f, {x, #}]] & /@ p;
  k = f - Total[r/(x - p)] // Together // FullSimplify;
  {r, p, CoefficientList[k, x]}]
```

Let's go through Nasser's examples:

```
residue[{2, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}]
(*    {{-0.0708358, 0.535418 - 1.03899 I, 0.535418 + 1.03899 I},
       {-0.682328, 0.341164 - 1.16154 I, 0.341164 + 1.16154 I},
       {2}}                                                         *)

residue[{-4, 8}, {1, 6, 8}]
(*    {{-12, 8},
       {-4, -2}, 
       {}}          *)

residue[{2, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}]
(*    {{1/2 + I, 1/2 - I},
       {-I, I},
       {-2, 0, 2}}            *)
```

Comment: When I run `residue[{1},{-3.,2.,0.,0.,0.}]` I get a message `CoefficientList::poly: 0. +0.5/x^3+0.75/x^2-2.25/x is not a polynomial.` and incorrect results for `r` and `k`

Comment: For the same example in Matlab, `[r,p,k]=residue([1],[-3,2,0,0,0])` I obtain `r = [-1.1250 1.1250 0.7500 0.5000]`, `p = [0.6667 0 0 0]`, `k = [ ]`

Comment: Yes, there's a problem in this code for higher-order roots (in this case, $x=0$ is a third-order root). The problem lies in the calculation of $k$, it needs to be adapted and I don't know how. Maybe ask at [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com) for a robust algorithm?

Comment: I don't think the Matlab answer is a correct decomposition: $-\frac98/(x - \frac23) + \frac98/x + \frac34/x + \frac12/x$ is not the same as your input polynomial $1/(2 x^3 - 3 x^4)$. What is the correct answer for this case?

Comment: You are indeed correct. The Matlab decomposition is wrong. (sorry for not checking, I assumed Matlab was doing it properly). Matlab's documentation states _Numerically,the partial fraction expansion of a ratio of polynomials represents an ill-posed problem.If the denominator polynomial,a(x), is near a polynomial with multiple roots,then small changes in the data,including roundoff errors,can result in arbitrarily large changes in the resulting poles and residues._ I guess `residue([1],[-3,2,0,0,0])` is such a case, i.e.,$\frac{1}{-3x^4 + 2x^3}$ cannot be written in the form of eq. (1).

Answer (score 10):

This is cheating, but:

```
num = FromDigits[{2, 1, 0, 0}, x]
den = FromDigits[{1., 0, 1, 1}, x]

(* Out[7]= x^2 (1 + 2 x)

Out[8]= 1 + x + 1. x^3 *)

In[10]:= IncompletePFD[num, den]

(* Out[10]= (2. + 0. I) + (
 0.535417905939 + 1.03899170871 I)/((-0.341163901914 - 1.1615414 I) + 
  x) + (0.535417905939 - 
  1.03899170871 I)/((-0.341163901914 + 1.1615414 I) + x) - (
 0.0708358118772 + 0. I)/(0.682327803828 + x) *)
```

[`IncompletePFD`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/IncompletePFD) is in the Wolfram Function Repository and is available as `ResourceFunction["IncompletePFD"]`. It does (or at least tries to do) what the name implies, the so-called "incomplete" partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: And why is it cheating? (Yes, I'm allowed to ask myself such questions, my memory is that bad.)

Answer (score 5):

I just saw the other answer uses some build in function to find the residues which I did not know about and which might be more efficient that what I did below. So this is something that can be improved in the function below if needed.

```
residue[numer0_, denom0_] := 
 Module[{x, result, k, roots, numer, denom, factors, n, p1, p2, p3},
  numer = FromDigits[numer0, x];
  denom = FromDigits[denom0, x];
  If[Length[numer0] >= Length[denom0],
     k = PolynomialQuotient[numer, denom, x];
     k = CoefficientList[k, x],
     k = {}
  ];
  roots = x /. NSolve[denom == 0, x];
  factors = Flatten@Last@Reap@Do[
     If[n == 1,
          p1 = roots[[2 ;; -1]],
          p1 = roots[[Join[Range[1, n - 1], Range[n + 1, Length[roots]]]]]
     ];
     p2 = (Times @@ ((x - #) & /@ p1)) /. x -> roots[[n]];
     p3 = numer /. x -> roots[[n]];
     Sow[Simplify[p3/p2]]
     , 
     {n, 1, Length[roots]}
  ];
  {Reverse@Chop@factors, Reverse@Chop@roots, k}
  ]
```

**Example 1**

```
numer = {2, 1, 0, 0};
denom = {1, 0, 1, 1};
{r, p, k} = residue[numer, denom];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Matlab:

```
>> numerator = [2 1 0 0];
>> denominator = [1 0 1 1];
>> [r,p,k] = residue(numerator,denominator)

r =    
   0.5354 + 1.0390i
   0.5354 - 1.0390i
  -0.0708 + 0.0000i        
p =    
   0.3412 + 1.1615i
   0.3412 - 1.1615i
  -0.6823 + 0.0000i

k =    
     2
```

**Example 2**

```
numer = {-4, 8};
denom = {1, 6, 8};
{r, p, k} = residue[numer, denom];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Matlab:

```
>> numerator = [-4 8];
denomenator = [1 6 8];
[r,p,k] = residue(numerator ,denomenator)

r =    
   -12
     8
p =    
    -4
    -2
k =    
     []
```

**example 3**

```
numer = {2, 0, 0, 1, 0};
denom = {1, 0, 1};
{r, p, k} = residue[numer, denom];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Matlab

```
>> b = [2 0 0 1 0];
a = [1 0 1];
[r,p,k] = residue(b,a)

r =    
   0.5000 - 1.0000i
   0.5000 + 1.0000i

p =    
   0.0000 + 1.0000i
   0.0000 - 1.0000i    

k =    
     2     0    -2
```

Answer (score 3):

It has been mentioned in other answers that the case of the denominator having multiple roots is problematic. One should then recall what `Residue[]` actually does, and instead use the more general functionality of `Series[]` to get the necessary components of the partial fraction decomposition.

Let us demonstrate on two of Nasser's examples. Here's an easy one with complex residues:

```
rat = FromDigits[{2, 0, 0, 1, 0}, x]/FromDigits[{1, 0, 1}, x];

{num, den} = {Numerator[rat], Denominator[rat]};
{pp, rem} = PolynomialQuotientRemainder[num, den, x];

pfd = pp + Total[Normal[FullSimplify[Series[rem/den, {x, #, -1}]] & /@
                                     DeleteDuplicates[x /. Solve[den == 0, x]]]]
   -2 + 2 x^2 + (1/2 - I)/(-I + x) + (1/2 + I)/(I + x)
```

and a slightly harder case with an irreducible denominator:

```
rat = FromDigits[{2, 1, 0, 0}, x]/FromDigits[{1, 0, 1, 1}, x]

{num, den} = {Numerator[rat], Denominator[rat]};
{pp, rem} = PolynomialQuotientRemainder[num, den, x];

pfd = pp + Total[Normal[FullSimplify[Series[rem/den, {x, #, -1}]] & /@
                                     DeleteDuplicates[x /. Solve[den == 0, x,
                                                                 Cubics -> False]]]]
   2 + Root[3 + 40 #1 - 31 #1^2 + 31 #1^3 &, 1]/(x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^3 &, 1]) + 
   Root[3 + 40 #1 - 31 #1^2 + 31 #1^3 &, 2]/(x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^3 &, 2]) + 
   Root[3 + 40 #1 - 31 #1^2 + 31 #1^3 &, 3]/(x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^3 &, 3])
```

where `Cubics -> False` was necessary to prevent needless complexity.

Now for examples with multiple roots. Here is a relatively simple one:

```
rat = (37 - 72 x + 20 x^2 + 25 x^3 + x^4 + x^5 - 7 x^6 - x^7 + x^8)/
      (12 - 28 x + 11 x^2 + 14 x^3 - 8 x^4 - 2 x^5 + x^6);

{num, den} = {Numerator[rat], Denominator[rat]};
{pp, rem} = PolynomialQuotientRemainder[num, den, x];

pfd = pp + Total[Normal[FullSimplify[Series[rem/den, {x, #, -1}]] & /@
                                     DeleteDuplicates[x /. Solve[den == 0, x]]]]
   3 + 271/(200 (-3 + x)) - 5/(18 (-1 + x)^3) - 61/(108 (-1 + x)^2) - 149/(216 (-1 + x)) +
   x + x^2 - 19/(135 (2 + x)^2) + 226/(675 (2 + x))
```

Check:

```
Simplify[Together[pfd - rat]]
   0
```

Here is a more difficult case:

```
rat = (-17 - 39 x - 26 x^2 + 30 x^3 + 45 x^4 + 15 x^5 - 17 x^6 - 9 x^7 -
       4 x^8 + 2 x^9 + x^10)/
      (-6 - 11 x - 3 x^2 + 15 x^3 + 11 x^4 - 4 x^5 - 8 x^6 + x^7 + x^8);
```

Perform the procedure once more:

```
{num, den} = {Numerator[rat], Denominator[rat]};
{pp, rem} = PolynomialQuotientRemainder[num, den, x];

pfd = pp + Total[Normal[FullSimplify[Series[rem/den, {x, #, -1}]] & /@
                                     DeleteDuplicates[x /. Solve[den == 0, x]]]];
```

This time, I have mercifully suppressed the output. Nevertheless, here is how to check the result:

```
Collect[Numerator[Together[pfd - rat]], x, RootReduce]
   0
```

Note that this procedure is intended for polynomials with exact coefficients; involving inexact numbers is a much thornier problem, involving the decision of when to take a cluster of roots as a single multiple root. Encapsulation of this method into a routine is left as an exercise.